# editorconfig - spaces inside of curly braces

Tags: jsx, eslint, prettier, editorconfig

I'm using Prettier and there is an `.editorconfig` file in the project. As such my VS Code configuration is getting overwritten. I can't delete the file and so I'm looking for how the allow the following rule using `.editorconfig`: [Enforce spaces inside of curly braces](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-curly-spacing.md)

That is - set spaces before and after content in curly braces JSX

Answer (score -5):

This has nothing to do with EditorConfig. Being an opinionated tool, Prettier doesn't allow customizing such little things. Use [`eslint-config-prettier`](https://github.com/prettier/eslint-config-prettier#readme) to disable ESLint rules that conflict with Prettier.

Comment: It has a lot to do with [tag:editorconfig]. It tells the IDE how to format the imports. In IntelliJ it is the option `Preferences | Editor | Code Style | TypeScript |  Spaces | ES6 import/export`. But a setting in [tag:editorconfig] would be cooler.